# Why is ActiveRecord and/or MySQL having a problem with this character?

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, utf-8, character-encoding

When I insert certain strings coming in from API calls into my db, they get cut off at certain characters. This is with ruby 1.8.7. I have everything set to utf8 app-wide and in MySQL. I typically don't have any problem entering utf8 content into the DB in other parts of the app.

It's supposed to be "El Soldado y La Muñeca". If I insert it into the db, only this makes it in: "11 El Soldado y La Mu".

```
>> name
=> "11 El Soldado y La Mu?eca(1).mp3"
>> name[20..20]
=> "u"
>> name[21..21]
=> "\361"
>> name[22..22]
=> "e"
```

1. is that a utf8 character?
2. i know that ruby 1.8 isn't encoding aware, but to be honest i always forget how this should affect me -- i always just set everything at all the other layers to utf8 and everything is fine. WHY THIS NO WORK NOW?

**update**

CORRECTION-- i was wrong, it's not coming from the api, it's coming from the file system.

**the wrongly-encoded character is coming from *inside the house*!**

new question: [How can I get utf8 characters from File#path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266815/how-can-i-get-utf8-characters-from-filepath)

Comment: I am not a Ruby man so this may be a dumb suggestion, but is the *connection* encoding also set to UTF-8? I think it defaults to ISO-8859-1 on every platform

Comment: yep, the connection is set to utf8 too

Comment: see my new question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266815/how-can-i-get-utf8-characters-from-filepath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are somehow getting a [Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1) (AKA ISO-8859-1) `ñ` rather than a UTF-8 `ñ`. In Latin-1 the `ñ` is 361 in octal (hence your single byte `"\361"`). In UTF-8 that lower case tilde-n should be `\303\261` (i.e. bytes 0303 and 0261 in octal or 0xc3 and 0xb1 in hex).

You might have to start playing with [Iconv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/classes/Iconv.html) in the Ruby side to make sure you get everything in UTF-8.

Comment: alright, i've been asking the wrong question (again). see update above and this new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266815/how-can-i-get-utf8-characters-from-filepath

Comment: @Pekka: And you were on the right track with the ISO-8859-1. Any byte that starts with "3" makes me think of octal, I had to look up the Latin-1 table though.